# Ansible Can't connect to Azure VM which is created by Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

## Rewrite the Qusestion

When I use `azure_rm – Azure Resource Manager inventory plugin`,
how can I change the ssh user connecting to the Azure VM?

## The old Question

I troubled that the Ansible in my azure cloud shell can't connect the Azure VM which is created by the Ansible playbook.
Another Ansible can connect the Azure VM which is created by the command line.
What's difference about the VM?

I created the 2 Azure VM.
The one is by the Ansible playbook.
Another one is by the the command line `az vm create`.

### The Ansible playbook `create_vm_for_the_developers.yaml`

```
- name: Create Azure VM
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "ResourceGroup"
      prompt: "Please input your resourcegroup"
      default: "defaultResourceGroupForVM" 
      private: no
    - name: "domain_name"
      prompt: "Please input your domain"
      default: "foobardomain" 
      private: no
    - name: "subscription_id"
      prompt: "Please input your subscription_id"
      default: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      private: no
  tasks:
  - name: Create resource group
    azure_rm_resourcegroup:
      name:  "{{ ResourceGroup }}"
      location: eastus
      subscription_id: "{{subscription_id}}"
  - name: Create virtual network
    azure_rm_virtualnetwork:
      resource_group: "{{ ResourceGroup }}"
      name: myVnet
      address_prefixes: "10.0.0.0/16"
      subscription_id: "{{subscription_id}}"
  - name: Add subnet
    azure_rm_subnet:
      resource_group: "{{ ResourceGroup }}"
      name: mySubnet
      address_prefix: "10.0.1.0/24"
      virtual_network: myVnet
      subscription_id: "{{subscription_id}}"
  - name: Create public IP address
    azure_rm_publicipaddress:
      resource_group: "{{ ResourceGroup }}"
      allocation_method: Static
      name: myPublicIP
      subscription_id: "{{subscription_id}}"
    register: output_ip_address
  - name: Dump public IP for VM which will be created
    debug:
      msg: "The public IP is {{ output_ip_address.state.ip_address }}."
  - name: Create Network Security Group that allows SSH
    azure_rm_securitygroup:
      resource_group: "{{ ResourceGroup }}"
      name: myNetworkSecurityGroup
      subscription_id: "{{subscription_id}}"
      rules:
        - name: SSH
          protocol: Tcp
          destination_port_range: 22
          access: Allow
          priority: 1001
          direction: Inbound
  - name: Create virtual network inteface card
    azure_rm_networkinterface:
      resource_group: "{{ ResourceGroup }}"
      subscription_id: "{{subscription_id}}"
      name: myNIC
      virtual_network: myVnet
      subnet: mySubnet
      public_ip_name: myPublicIP
      security_group: myNetworkSecurityGroup
      ip_configurations:
      - name: ipconfig1
        public_ip_address_name: myPublicIP
        primary: True
  - name: Create VM
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      resource_group: "{{ ResourceGroup }}"
      subscription_id: "{{subscription_id}}"
      name: myVM
      vm_size: Standard_DS1_v2
      admin_username: azureuser
      #admin_password: Azure12345678
      ssh_password_enabled: false
      ssh_public_keys:
        - path: /home/azureuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
          key_data: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"  
      network_interfaces: myNIC
      image:
        offer: CentOS
        publisher: OpenLogic
        sku: '7.5'
        version: latest
```

I run the command `ansible-playbook create_vm_for_the_developers.yaml` and create the VM.

### the command line `az vm create`

```
az vm create --resource-group defaultResourceGroupForVM              --name ansible-inventory-test-vm2              --image CentOS  --ssh-key-values ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I also runned the above command.

### Dynamic inventories `infra_azure_rm.yaml`

```
plugin: azure_rm
include_vm_resource_groups:
- defaultResourceGroupForVM
auth_source: auto
exclude_host_filters:
# excludes hosts that are powered off
- powerstate != 'running'
```

### I runned the command

```sh
ansible all -m ping -i infra_azure_rm.yaml
```

### Error result

```
myVM_caa6 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).",
    "unreachable": true
}
ansible-inventory-test-vm2_62bd | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

### Env

- on Azure Clound Shell
- Ansible version: 2.8.1
- ssh key is created by the command `ssh-keygen`

### PLus the Information

- Of course both VMs can be connected via ssh.
- The username for ssh connection differs between the VM created on the command line and the VM created in Ansible. This may be a problem seriously.
- In dynamic inventory option, we can change the username for the ssh?

### Plus Plus the Informatin

- [`azure_rm`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.html#parameters) 's `ad_user` param is for the Azure AD.
- How can I change the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shows the permission denied, it means you can connect to the VM, but fail to authenticate.

When you run the command, you do not set the username which the VM use and the default username maybe not right. So it may be the reason which causes the error. You can try the command like this to set the real username:

```
ansible all -m ping -i infra_azure_rm.yaml --user=USERNAME
```

If you need any more help, please let me know.